# MySQL Proxy net start proxy issue

Tags: mysql, windows, proxy

I tried to follow official MySQL 5.1 Reference manual to get started working with MySQL Proxy. From the very beginning the manual suggests creating the service in this way:

```
C:\> sc create "Proxy" DisplayName= "MySQL Proxy" start= "auto" »
binPath= "C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-proxy-0.8.2\bin\mysql-proxy-svc.exe »
--proxy-backend-addresses=127.0.0.1:3306"
```

I did it right and no error appeared after running this command, however when I run

```
net start proxy
```

I get an error "Incorrect service name" (Неправильное имя службы in Russian).

Answer (score 0):

I got it. As one blogger says, "It turns out that a literal, precise interpretation of the command line arguments is needed". Just follow this [link](http://blog.wassupy.com/2011/02/trouble-creating-windows-services-with.html), if you encounter the same problem